# How load paper.js in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, paperjs

I use paper.js in my frontent application. I use gulp. This is my gulp code:

```
gulp.src([
    // .... other vendor js scripts
    'node_modules/paper/dist/paper-full.js'
])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(target))
```

but now I need use paper.js in webpack. I try use code like this:

```
 import paper from 'paper'
```

but after this, when I try call paper methods (for example const path = new paper.Path() ) I got error

> Cannot read property 'Path' of undefined"

**UPDATE:**

I use **vuejs webpack** template for my application, my [webpack.base.conf.js here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js)

Comment: Can you attach your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Joshua Barnett, I add link to _webpack.config.js_ in question update

Comment: How about the new ES6 import/export feature? Can't seem to load it

Comment: Your error is simply because you need to call setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
import * as paper from 'paper'
```

or
And there is a loader for paper.js
https://github.com/aprowe/paper-loader

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.paper.js$/,
        loader: "paper-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: You don't need a loader for loading a single library. Paper.js exports itself as a CommonJS module so you can import it directly from `node_modules` using webpack.

Comment: How about the new ES6 import/export feature? Can't seem to load it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import paper from 'paper';
paper.setup([640, 480]);
let paperCircle = new paper.Path.Circle([0, 0], 50);
```

Comment: `import paper from 'paper';`
works for me